# Init services does not start at Boot time

Tags: root-access, fastboot, magisk, vivo

I flashed Patch Boot.img via fastboot after flash device start normally but didn't get Root Access..
When i try to get boot logcat i observed that my device didn't start init services at boot time...
Boot.img Contains Ramdisk & Init. Rc files
Device:
Vivo S1, Android 11 version,
Chipset MT6768 Helio P65

Comment: https://github.com/topjohnwu/Magisk/issues/5148